# Overriding streambuf for an fstream

Tags: c++, stl

I am porting very old legacy code from VS2008 to VS2013.  Part of this code base is a fairly complicated file logging lib that overrides streambuf and associates it with an fstream.  It does this through inheritance of both streambuf and fstream.

But when I try to link the generated DLL with another DLL that uses it I get:

```
1>syscored.lib(syscored.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall
std::basic_fstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::close(void)"
(?close@?$basic_fstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) already
defined in iptsrvfl.obj 
1>syscored.lib(syscored.dll) : error LNK2005:
"public: void __thiscall std::basic_fstream<char,struct
std::char_traits<char> >::`vbase destructor'(void)"
(??_D?$basic_fstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) already
defined in iptsrvfl.obj
```

Basically, inheriting from fstream causes that DLL to export some of the symbols of fstream.  My class that uses that DLL also uses a standard fstream instance and the symbols for close() and dtor() are seen as already defined.

I've tried changing the fstream-derived class to use containment instead of inheritance, but there's no way to associate the custom streambuf with the contained stream.  It is simply not exposed through the public interface.  (We're calling init( streambuf ) in the ctor of the fstream).

Can someone tell me:
1) how to associate the streambuf with a contained fstream, OR
2) how to avoid this symbol clash.

Thanks.

Comment: "inheritance of both streambuf and fstream". Does the same class inherits both streambuf and fstream, or two different classes?

Comment: Two different classes.  The streambuf-derived class is not really my problem.  The problem is how I associate it with an fstream.

Comment: Looks like the legacy code is doing it right by the book. Don't see any problem with that. Show how you link your DLLs (the full linker command).

Comment: Are you using include guards (or `#pragma once`)?

Comment: @0x499602D2: That's a compile-time thing, not link time.

Comment: /OUT:"..." /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"..." /DYNAMICBASE "psapi.lib" "setupapi.lib" "crypt32.lib" "wsock32.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" "ecrobjd.lib" "binportd.lib" "oswrapd.lbi" "syscored.lib" /IMPLIB:"../lib/syscmmnd.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"..." /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"..." /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"..\..\common\lib" /LIBPATH:"..\lib" /TLBID:1

Comment: Yeah, sorry I realized that I pasted the wrong one.

Comment: I've solved my problem by inlining everything in the fstream-derived class and removing the __declspec.  This kind of stuff frustrates me, because I study it enough to solve my problem, but never enough to understand why.  How does inheriting from an STL class and exporting my derived class cause me to be unable to use the base STL class after an import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an exported class inherits from a template instantiation that is not explicitly exported, then the compiler implicitly exports this template instantiation. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twa2aw10.aspx). You don't want to do that as it will lead to the precise sort of errors you're seeing.

So you should not export your logger class, just as you've done. In fact you should rarely export classes. If you need to make *instances* of your class available outside of your DLL, export a class factory (a function). Export a class only if you want others to inherit from it, and never export any templates of any kind. You may export specific template instantiations.

If you need to inherit from a standard library template, and want others to inherit your class further, you may have to make it a header-only all-inline class, or maybe selectively export its methods but not the class itself.

Comment: Thank you.  Very well explained.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably avoid the symbol clash by linking to the CRT DLL. Static linking only makes sense if you're either compiling a standalone EXE or alternatively a DLL which does not export any Standard C++ types (i.e. pure C interface or COM DLL).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by static linking.  I'm linking to the import lib of the generated DLL.

Comment: You're dynamically linking yo **your** DLL. How are you linking to the CRT? /MT or /MD ?

Comment: I'm using /MD and /MDd